# the exception with parsing a date YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss

Tags: java, date, formatting

I try to parse a date in the format YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss

```
String now = "2012-11-02 12:02:00";
DateFormat formatter;
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date date_temp = (Date) formatter.parse(now.toString());
System.out.println("output: " + date_temp);
```

It gives me following exception

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2012-11-02 12:02:00"
```

Comment: FYI you don't need to call `toString()` on `now` as `now` is already a string. Also `DateFormat.parse` returns a `Date` so you don't need to cast it to `Date`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well yes, you've created a formatted with one format ("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy") and then given it a string in a completely different format to parse. Why did you *think* that would work? Try this:

```
// Locale specified to avoid any cultural differences. You may also
// want to specify the time zone.
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                                            Locale.US);
Date date = formatter.parse(now);
```

Note that the parsed `Date` does *not* know anything about formatting - the result of calling `toString()` (as you're doing implicitly here) is always just the default format, in the JRE default time zone. If you want to print it out with a particular format, use `SimpleDateFormat` again.

Also note that I've combined declaration and initialization for the variable. Prefer that over declaring a variable in one line and giving it an initial value later.

Answer (score 2):

Of course your `date string` is not in the `format` you are using in `SimpleDateFormat`. So it won't be able to parse it into a `date object`.

Try using this: -

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```